# In Flask, how can I generate a dynamic URL upon button click?

Tags: python, html, flask

For example, now if I have two buttons in a form element, when you click on either one of them, you'll be directed to the corresponding profile.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('getProfile') }}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="profile1"> View Profile</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="profile2"> View Profile</button>
</form>
```

In my apprunner.py, I have

```
 @app.route('/profile', methods=['POST'])
 def getProfile():
       if request.form['submit'] = 'profile1':
            return render_template("profile1.html")
       else if request.form['submit'] = 'profile2':
            return render_template("profile2.html")
```

However, my problem is when I click on either button, the url will always be something like "127.0.0.1:5000/profile". But, I want it to look like "http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile1" or "http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile2".

I have looked for solution on how to generate dynamic URL online, but none of them works for button click.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@app.route('/profile<int:user>')                                                                                                   
def profile(user):                                                                                                             
    print(user)
```

You can test it on a REPL:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/profile<int:user>')
def profile(user):
    print(user)

ctx = app.test_request_context()
ctx.push()

flask.url_for('.profile', user=1)
'/profile1'
```

EDIT:

how you pass the `user` parameter to your new route depends on what you need. If you need hardcoded routes for `profile1` and `profile2` you can pass `user=1` and `user=2` respectively. If you want to generate those links programatically, depends on how these profiles are stored.

Otherwise you could `redirect` instead of `render_template`, to the `url_for` with the parsed element in the request object. This means having two routes

```
@app.route('/profile<int:user>')
def profile_pretty(user):
    print(user)

@app.route('/profile', methods=['POST'])
def getProfile():
      if request.form['submit'] = 'profile1':
           return redirect(url_for('.profile_pretty', user=1))
       else if request.form['submit'] = 'profile2':
            return redirect(url_for('.profile_pretty', user=2))
```

> **caveat**: This would make your routes look like you want, but this is inefficient as it generates a new request each time, just to make your urls the way you want. At this point it's safe to ask *why* do you want to have dynamically generated routes for static content.

---

As explained in http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#url-converters

> When you define a route in Flask, you can specify parts of it that will be converted into Python variables and passed to the view function.

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def profile(username):
    pass
```

> Whatever is in the part of the URL labeled  will get passed to the view as the username argument. You can also specify a converter to filter the variable before it’s passed to the view.

```
@app.route('/user/id/<int:user_id>')
def profile(user_id):
    pass
```

> In this code block, the URL http://myapp.com/user/id/Q29kZUxlc3NvbiEh will return a 404 status code – not found. This is because the part of the URL that is supposed to be an integer is actually a string.
>
> We could have a second view that looks for a string as well. That would be called for /user/id/Q29kZUxlc3NvbiEh/ while the first would be called for /user/id/124.

Comment: so, do I need to change anything on "url_for" in HTML since it accepts an profile() accepts an argument

Comment: if you require parameters in the route, calling `url_for` without an argument will raise an exception. You need to provide user=<value>. You can also add some defaults as documented in the flask [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#url-route-registrations), check the examples there given.

Comment: If I wanna pass the value of the buttons, "profile1" or "profile2", to user in "url_for", am I able to do it? Cuz, I can't see that in the doc

Comment: Uhm I would say that's another problem, and I got it wrong. Based on this bit "*But, I want it to look like "http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile1" or "http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile2".*" you'd want to redirect a `/profile` route to a new generated route that uses the value in the request object. I'll edit my answer, but it seems that that is not necessary, i.e. this is an [XY problem](https://artyom.me/yx).

Comment: why do you print the user in the first function instead of render_template? We're using it in the url_for();

Comment: @ronn Lee because it was intended to work as an example of how you'd generate dynamic URLs. You would have to parse the number and render each template accordingly, or you could redirect to different static URLs instead. I don't know the details of what you are trying to accomplish, but it seems you could refactor your code and/or avoid resorting to dynamic urls. *Why do you need dynamic urls?*

Comment: Got it. It totally makes sense now. I need dynamic URL, because my website will have different profiles corresponding to different users, and I want each profile page have a unique URL. Like in facebook, the link of each profile has a format of "www.facebook.com/<username>". So that when person one sends a the URL to person two, person two can load the profile upon clicking on the URL.

Comment: Then you need dynamic urls, but that belongs more to a design pattern that does not rely on hardcoded values on your template, and rather having those ids retrieved from a database by means of an ORM layer or a database driver like psycopg2 and/or Jinja, but that's another topic. I would suggest you give a read to Miguel Grinberg's book on Flask, as it covers a lot of the basics with Flask.

Comment: Yea, in my actual application, I don't use hardcoded values, instead I retrieve value from MySQL database upon clicking on the button and use the button value as a primary key to retrieve the data. In my example, I am just making it easier to understand.

Comment: @ronnLee I think that in this case it suggested a different problem. I'd imagine you retrieve the value in the buttons dynamically using jinja from current_user or whatever user object you are passing when rendering that template. Anyway, did I truly solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, the problem has been solved. Thanks so much for your time! :)