# How to create URL query string in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, query-string

I am using flask and python3 to upload a video on server. The result is saved in format(filename)+result.jpg , where filename is the videoname

This image result was visible on browser with url /video_feed before appending result.jpg with string
How can I now access the url to see result.jpg

```
@app.route('/video_feed_now')
def video_feed_now():
    #return send_file('result.jpg', mimetype='image/gif')
    return send_file(format(filename)+'result.jpg', frame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
cv2.imwrite(format(filename)+'result.jpg', frame)

@app.route('/video_feed_now/<filename>')
def video_feed_now(filename):

return send_file(format(filename), mimetype='image/gif')
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable $frame is undefined.

In your case, I suggest to use `send_from_directory`.

Here is usage sample.

```
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename, as_attachment=False)
```

Besides, you can refer this [In Flask, how can I generate a dynamic URL upon button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639744/in-flask-how-can-i-generate-a-dynamic-url-upon-button-click)

Comment: Unable to resolve this query.  **NameError: name 'filename' is not defined** `def generateForImage():
 while percentageProcessed <= 99:
  time.sleep(5)
  with app.app_context():
   with open(format(filename)+'server.log', 'r') as fh:

    
    yield fh.read()` `@app.route('/result_now') #
def result_now():
 with open("server.log", 'r') as fh:

  return fh.read()`